# Add context menu in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: search bar image]

Need to add a context menu to the search bar.

There is no configuration for this section in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus).
Is it possible to add this context menu?

Comment: add a feature request to the VSC repo